# Problem with emitting from 2 child components into 1 parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm emitting a value (which is always 1 or -1) to parent component, everytime a click event happens in child component.

When i press click events from only one child component, i'm getting the value as it should be. But when i start pressing from other component too, total value resets. I need total to not reset and keep increasing or reducing with the value*2 operation all the way no matter which component i press from.

How can i block this value reset when i start pressing from other child component?

```
<!-- here is Parent Component. -->

<script setup>

import ChildComp1 from "./ChildComp1.vue";
import ChildComp2 from "./ChildComp2.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

const total =ref(0);

</script>

<!-- Now inserting 2 ChildComps to template:  -->

<template>
  <div>

<ChildComp1
       @increment="(value) => (total = value * 2)"
       @reduce="(value) => (total = value * 2)"
   />

<ChildComp2
       @increment="(value) => (total = value * 2)"
       @reduce="(value) => (total = value * 2)"
   />

    <h3><span>Total:</span> ${{ total }}.00</h3>

  </div>
</template>
```

```
<!--  and here is the childcomps, they are same so i share only 1 code --> 

<script setup>

import { ref } from "vue";

const amount = ref(0);

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button
        class="button2"
        @click="amount--, $emit('reduce', amount)"
      ></button>
      <p class="amount">{{ amount }}</p>
      <button
        class="button1"
        @click="amount++, $emit('increment', amount)"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: or is there any better way to implement this kind of thing?

Comment: Please share the code of child components

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim sorry added.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim okay i found the solution, thank you. will be sharing now

Comment: Is the `total` on your parent component supposed to be a sum of the child components * any quantity (like a shopping cart where your child comps are products and the multiplier is the amount)?

If so, you need to fix the logic in the `@increment` and `@reduce` listeners. They can't directly change `total` since `total` does not depend only on each child component information.

In case I got the logic wrong, you can dismiss my comment.

Comment: @el.mano.el exactly, i handled the situation at my bottom message

Answer (score 0):

When you send the value from the second child component which equals to 0 will reset the `total` since `0*2=0`, try to reassign the total using `+=` or `-=` operators :

```html
<ChildComp1
       @increment="(value) => (total += value * 2)"
       @reduce="(value) => (total -= value * 2)"
   />

<ChildComp2
       @increment="(value) => (total += value * 2)"
       @reduce="(value) => (total -= value * 2)"
   />
```

Comment: at first i was thinking to solve this problem like this, but this breaks the `value*2` after first click, it starts increasing more than `value*2` after first click event

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution by making 1 more change onto @Boussadjra Brahim's answer.

```
<!-- after implementing operator changes on parent component: -->

<!-- ParentComp -->

<ChildComp1
      @increment="(value) => (total += value * 2)"
      @reduce="(value) => (total -= value * 2)"
    />
<ChildComp2
      @increment="(value) => (total += value * 2)"
      @reduce="(value) => (total -= value * 2)"
    />
```

```
<!--  I needed to make one more change on child components; we are 
not emitting the "amount", we emit just 1 --> 

<!-- ChildComp -->

<div class="buttons">
        <button class="button2" @click="amount--, $emit('reduce', 1)">
          <img class="down-arrow" src="../ico/arrow.svg" />
        </button>
        <p class="amount">{{ amount }}</p>
        <button class="button1" @click="amount++, $emit('increment', 1)">
          <img class="up-arrow" src="../ico/arrow.svg" />
        </button>
      </div>
```